# Input unicode characters in a WPF TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, input, textbox, keyboard

In my WPF application, I want to input the unicode character 9837 ('♭') in a TextBox. When I try (using LeftAlt+9837), the textbox displays the character 'm' instead.

I tried to change the FontFamily of the TextBox but it didn't change anything. In debug, the TextBox receives the character 'm' and not '♭'.

Doing the same (LeftAlt+9837) in Microsoft Word works fine.

Any idea?

EDIT:
I can copy/paste this character from Word to the TextBox and it works. I need a way to input unicode characters in a TextBox without copy/pasting it. I thought that using Alt+9837 was the easiest way but apparently it doesn't work.

I can reproduce this very easily using the following code:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="Me">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=Me, Path=MyText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow));

    public string MyText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can reproduce your "error". If it is an error.
I get "m" everywhere for the ASCII code 9837.
Maybe Microsoft Word uses a different encoding?

Comment: Where are you getting that ♭ is ASCII 9837?  ASCII does not go to 9837.  9837 is the HTML of ♭.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AD The unicode is U+266D.

Comment: 266D (hexadecimal) is the same thing as 9837 (decimal)

Comment: The HTML code for this character is &#9837;

Comment: http://unicode-table.com/en/#266D